# How to enable disk access on Ipad mini?

Tags: ipad

I remember there used to be a check box that allows "enable disk access", but now iTunes 10 has taken away that check box. What should I do if I want to enable my Ipad mini for disk access (preferably without using a 3rd party software..)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable Disk Access was a feature on the iPods, but has never been an option on the iPhone, iPod Touch, or iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Some jailbreak-only tweaks have allowed for creating a disk image to be made accessible as a standard flash drive over USB, but their historical records in compatibility - both relatively to iOS updates and towards Windows systems- is very poor. For that matter, none of them is known to work on iOS 6.1.